# Get Month columns from datetime column and count entries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
| ID | Name | DateA       | TimeToWork | TimeWorked |
|:--:|:----:|:----------:|:----------:|:----------:|
| 1  |Frank | 2013-01-01 |     8      |     5      |
| 2  |Frank | 2013-01-02 |     8      |     NULL   | 
| 3  |Frank | 2013-01-03 |     8      |     7      |
| 4  |Jules | 2013-01-01 |     4      |     9      |
| 5  |Jules | 2013-01-02 |     4      |     NULL   |
| 6  |Jules | 2013-01-03 |     4      |     3      |
```

The table is very long, every person has an entry for every day in a year. For each person I have the Date he worked (`DateA`), the hours he has to work according to contract (`TimeToWork`) and the hours he worked (`TimeWorked`). As you can see some days a person didnt work on a day he had to. This is when a person took a full day overtime.

What I try to accomplish is to get the following table out of the first one above.

```
| Name | January    | Feburary | March | ... | Sum |
|:----:|:----------:|:--------:|:-----:|:---:|:---:|
|Frank | 2          |     0    | 1     | ... | 12  |
|Jules | 5          |     1    | 3     | ... | 10  |
```

For each month I want to count all days where a person took A FULL day off and sum all up in the `Sum` column.

I tried something like `Select (case when Datetime(month, DateA = 1 then count(case when timetowork - (case when timeworked then 0 end) = timetowork then 1 else 0 end) end) as 'January'` but my TSQL is just not that good and the code doent work at all. Btw using this my select command would be about 40 lines.

I really would appreciate if anyone could help me or give me a link to a good source so I can read myself into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, than Gordon Linoff's answer is a good beginning, but doesn't deal with "full day off".

```
select Name,
       sum(case when month(DateA) = 01 and TimeWorked is null then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when month(DateA) = 02 and TimeWorked is null then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
       ...
       sum(case when month(DeteA) = 12 and TimeWorked is null then 1 else 0 end) as Dec,
       sum(case when TimeWorked is null then 1 else 0 end) as Sum
from table T
where year(DateA) = 2013
group by name
```

This method solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when month(datea) = 1 then timeworked else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when month(datea) = 2 then timeworked else 0 end) as Feb,
       . . .
       sum(case when month(datea) = 12 then timeworked else 0 end) as Dec,
       sum(timeworked)
from table t
where year(datea) = 2013
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` can be removed using bit logic

```
SELECT name
     , January = SUM((1 - CAST(MONTH(DateA) - 1 as bit)) 
                   * (1 - CAST(COALESCE(TimeWorked, 0) as bit)))
     , February = SUM((1 - CAST(MONTH(DateA) - 2 as bit)) 
                    * (1 - CAST(COALESCE(TimeWorked, 0) as bit)))
     ...
     , December = SUM((1 - CAST(MONTH(DateA) - 12 as bit)) 
                    * (1 - CAST(COALESCE(TimeWorked, 0) as bit)))
     , Total = SUM((1 - CAST(COALESCE(TimeWorked, 0) as bit)))
FROM   table1
GROUP BY name;
```

To check if there is a dayoff the formula is:

```
(1 - CAST(COALESCE(TimeWorked, 0) as bit))
```

that is equivalent to `TimeWorked IS NULL`: the `CAST` to `BIT` return 1 for every value different from 0, `1 - BIT` invert those values.

The month filter is:

```
(1 - CAST(MONTH(DateA) - %month% as bit))
```

using the same idea as before this formula return 1 only for the given month (the cast give 1 for every other month, the `1 - BIT` invert that result)

Multipling the two formulas we have the days off only for the given month

Answer (score 0):

You can get your required result by using pivot also. You can get more information about pivot here [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also you can get your output using the following query. I did it for up to April only. You can extend it up to December.

```
Select [Name], [January], [February], [March], [April]
From
(
Select Name, MName, DaysOff from
(
select Name, DATENAME(MM, dateA) MName, 
    count(case isnull(timeworked,0) when 0 then 1 else null end) DaysOff
    from tblPivot
    Where Year(DateA) = 2013
    group by Name, DATENAME(MM, dateA)
) A ) As B
pivot(Count(DaysOff)
For  MName in ([January], [February],[March],[April])
) As Pivottable;
```